# Matching two power signals for similarity

Tags: time-series, correlation, statistical-power, descriptive-statistics, cross-correlation

Below are the images of two signals that i plotted. Both the signals are from fridge belonging to different houses. Visually looking at the plot i can tell that these plots belong to fridge as they look very similar. But is there a way i can statistically compare the two graphs for similarity using the time series plot ?[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to look at the normalized [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). It is very widely used time-series similarity metric. In R use [ccf()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html) function.

If cross-correlation for some reason will appear unappropriate you can try other similarity metrics like [mutual information](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mutual_information) (look at its [Normalized variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Normalized_variants)) - this may catch nonlinear dependencies.